# addFileAttachmentAsync fails when trying to attach a static file on Outlook web app

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to get an attachment (a static file being served from my Flask Python development server), and attach it to my email in my outlook web app. It fails with the error message "The attachment cannot be added to the item." The error code is 9007 (AttachmentUploadGeneralFailure).

This is the code I am using (from the Microsoft docs) -

```
var attachmentURI = SERVER_IP + "/static/" + fileName;

Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync (
    attachmentURI,
    fileName,
    { asyncContext: null },
    function (asyncResult) {

        if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
            console.log(asyncResult.error.message);
            console.log(asyncResult.error);
        }
        else {
            // Get the ID of the attached file.
            var attachmentID = asyncResult.value;
            console.log('ID of added attachment: ' + attachmentID);
        }

    });
```

I can access the file on the browser (so the server part is handling GET requests correctly). The file size is about 100Kb. The server is over self signed https.

I believe the problem could be with: OWA doesn't allow self signed https, because I don't see any get/post requests from OWA on my server when addFileAttachmentAsync is called. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have added my server as an AppDomain in the manifest file. It still does not work.

Comment: Is this an Office365, or your own Exchange Server account? If you don't see requests on the server where you host the attachment, it means it's not reachable from the Exchange server (online or on-premises). That would be the first problem to solve. Then, self-signed https would likely not work. Note, the API does not require https, so you could try with http first to confirm.